# cvSetImageROI to detect eyes

Tags: c++, opencv

In the following code I'm trying to detect face and eye. from a video.
My problem is that I'm trying to set ROI to detect eyes . but I think there an error in cvSetImageROI funcition .

this error is displayed

error C2664: 'cvSetImageROI' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cv::Mat' to 'IplImage *'

Thanks for helping me

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
#include<opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include<vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

 int main()
{
CascadeClassifier face_cascade, eye_cascade;
if(!face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")) {
    printf("Error loading cascade file for face");
    return 1;
}
if(!eye_cascade.load("haarcascade_eye.xml")) {
    printf("Error loading cascade file for eye");
    return 1;
}
VideoCapture capture("w.mp4"); //-1, 0, 1 device id
if(!capture.isOpened())
{
    printf("error to initialize camera");
    return 1;
}
Mat cap_img,gray_img;
vector<Rect> faces, eyes;
while(1)
{
    capture >> cap_img;
    waitKey(10);
    cvtColor(cap_img, gray_img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::equalizeHist(gray_img,gray_img);
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, faces, 1.1, 10, CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE | CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(0,0), cvSize(300,300));
    for(int i=0; i < faces.size();i++)
    {
        Point pt1(faces[i].x+faces[i].width, faces[i].y+faces[i].height);
        Point pt2(faces[i].x,faces[i].y);
        Mat faceROI = gray_img(faces[i]);
        cvSetImageROI(faceROI, cvRect(faces->x,faces->y + (faces->height)/5,faces->width, (faces->height)/3 );
        eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30,30));
        for(size_t j=0; j< eyes.size(); j++)
        {
            //Point center(faces[i].x+eyes[j].x+eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y+eyes[j].y+eyes[j].height*0.5);
            Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );
            int radius = cvRound((eyes[j].width+eyes[j].height)*0.25);
            circle(cap_img, center, radius, Scalar(255,0,0), 2, 8, 0);
        }
        rectangle(cap_img, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0,255,0), 2, 8, 0);
    }
    imshow("Result", cap_img);
    waitKey(3);
    char c = waitKey(3);
    if(c == 27)
        break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use old openCV method. Your image is in the `Mat` format and `cvSetImageROI` cannot take `Mat` image as an argument.

**Suggestion:**

```
Rect region_of_interest = Rect(x, y, w, h);
Mat image_roi = image(region_of_interest);
```

Comment: How the region of eye is assigned in Rect (x,y,w,h)

Comment: I have taken it from your code: `faces->x,faces->y + (faces->height)/5,faces->width, (faces->height)/3`. You just need to write the same thing inside `Rect( -,-,-,-   );`

Comment: I applied the parameters as  aces->x,faces->y(faces->height)/5,faces->width(faces->height)/3                 this error is displayed                                                              'std::vector<_Ty>' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->

Comment: @sarmad: you asked about getting an error  due to the use of `cvSetImageROI ()`. The answer is about that problem. Please specify, are you still getting that error? and, what is your current problem exactly?

Comment: I have changed it to                                                                                               Rect region_of_interest = Rect(faces[i].x,faces[i].y + (faces[i].height)/5,faces[i].width, (faces[i].height)/3);
 Mat image_roi = image(region_of_interest);
It worked for a while and displayed                                                                                            Unhandled exception at 0x000007fefcebb3dd in Opencv_test_.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0017f5c0..

Comment: So, the question you asked has been solved. Now, the problem is related to the parameters you need to paas to `Rect()`. For that, you should read the openCV documentation. It is not really hard and one of the basic methods. You are getting this error because you are trying to do illegal memory access due to wrong value of parameters passed to `Rect()`.